# How to set the fixed xAxis value in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set the fixed xAxis value like that picture ,
[like that picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FeK2.png)
I tried to set this, but it can't :

```js
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
            var result = []
            let today = moment().subtract(4,`day`).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            let tomorrow = moment().subtract(3,`day`).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            result.push(moment(`${today} 06:00:00`).unix()*1000)
            result.push(moment(`${today} 12:00:00`).unix()*1000)
            result.push(moment(`${today} 18:00:00`).unix()*1000)
            result.push(moment(`${tomorrow} 00:00:00`).unix()*1000)
            result.push(moment(`${tomorrow} 06:00:00`).unix()*1000)
            result.info = this.tickPositions.info;
            return result;
          }
```

I don't know how to set these values ?

Comment: What do you mean by `Xyais value`? Your question seems to lack [information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't know how to upload the picture , I try again , if you saw the picture , you will understand

Comment: Let me just describe it in words !  I want my xAxis are fixed ,  like  "06:00 、12:00 、18:00、00:00、06:00 ",

Comment: And how does your current result look like? What is the code getting you stuck or causing problems? Your snippet above does not show anything at all.

Comment: I want to Know what API to set fixed xAxis . thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `xAxis.tickInterval` [API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickInterval) like this :

```
xAxis: {
  tickInterval: 21600000
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/kc5pugm6/)